# PHP logic problem

Tags: php, logic

I have a sql table `images` which has columns `id`,`imagePath`,``` caption``count ```.

To view those images what i do is, I ask for the page number and query the iamge

```
$limit=$page-1;
$sel=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,imagePath,caption,count from images".
                        " order by id desc limit ".$limit.",1");
```

This shows images correctly.

But i have another function which shows 4 random thumbnail of that images out of the total images from the database.With those images i also give a href tag so that when a user clicks on that link he is taken to the page of that image.

Now the problem is with those links.
Suppose i have images like these in the database

```
id=1
id=2
id=3
id=4
id=5
```

To find the page number of the specific id what i do is

```
$newid=$idOfTheCurrentImage-($idOfTheLastImage-1);
```

Using this logic i get

```
id=1  page=5
id=2  page=4
id=3  page=3
id=4  page=2
id=5  page=1
```

This gives correct results if all the ids are in order. But if anyone of the id is deleted this logic fails.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Why don't you just pass `id` instead of `page` (or both)? That would be easier and faster:`SELECT id,imagePath,caption,count from images where id = $id`

Comment: That would show the images in ascending order i want to show the recently added image first and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

- Adding another field, a 'sequential number' , so you have pairs ($id, $seq_number), and do your calculations as you did with $seq_number. Don't forget to update the sequential number field it on delete.
- Get all the id's on an array, and calculate over there. In this option, the $id value is not used in the calculations, you use only the array indexes.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thnaks will try it out and,soon let you know :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using something other than a running counter as the page-denominator. As you say, it is subject to change, or fail if a number is missing in between.

Your images have a caption. You could create a "slug" from that and use that as your page-denominator.

No more quirky maths or murky logic when creating links, no more disappearing pages.

Comment: Hey nice idea,Will surely use this in my future projects Thanks